# Get testing script filename and class name with nosetest

Tags: python, nosetests

I ran the `osetests --rednose --nocapture test_report.py`

I got `type` for `print(cls.__class__.__name__)`, but I expected `TestReport`

and `/usr/local/bin/nosetests` for `os.path.splitext(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)[0]`, but I expected `test_report`

How to get it ?

```
class TestReport(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        print(cls.__class__.__name__)
        ap(os.path.splitext(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__))
        TESTING_NAME=os.path.splitext(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)[0]
        print("testing script name:"+TESTING_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `cls` parameter is most certainly a `class`, the class of a class is of the type `type`, and that's what you got when you tried to get the `__name__` of it.  Just try `cls.__name__` and see if that gives you what you expect.